# Does Babel Runtime Tansform provide Object, Promise and Symbol support in IE?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, babeljs, es6-modules

The following code includes **dynamic import** test, `Object` test, `Symbol` and `Promise` tests.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$('#TestDynamicImport-Button').on('click', () => {
  loadModule();
});


async function loadModule() {
  const MODULE = await import('./TestModules/TestJsModule');
  console.log(MODULE.TEST1);
}


// Promise test
let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

console.log('Promise Test: ' + promise1);


// Symbol test

let obj = {};

obj[Symbol("a")] = "a";
obj[Symbol.for("b")] = "b";
obj["c"] = "c";
obj.d = "d";

for (let i in obj) {
  console.log(i); // logs "c" and "d"
}


// Object test
let obj1 = { foo: "bar", baz: 42 };
let map = new Map(Object.entries(obj1));
console.log(map); // Map { foo: "bar", baz: 42 }
```

As you know, `Promise`, `Object` and `Symbol` does not supported in IE, and to provide this support, **polyfill** required. Recently, to provide dynamic import support (`import()`) and `asyc`/`await` support, I added `syntax-dynamic-import` and `transform-runtime` babel plugins (below code is the part of webpack configuration):

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['env', {'modules': false}]
              ],
              plugins: [
                'syntax-dynamic-import',
                'transform-runtime'
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Although I don't use polyfill in this example, there is no any errors in IE console before dynamic import (by other words, `Object`, `Promise` and `Symbol` works in IE thanks to `transform-runtime`):

[image]

However, if to try dinamic import (in this example - by clicking button),
`Error: “ReferenceError: Promise is not defined”` error will occur.

[image]

(`定義されていません`means `not defined`)

How you can explain it? `Promise` works fine before dynamic import ...

```
let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});
```

Comment: The error says `promise` with lower case p. You probably have a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: @a better oliver, I make mistake here, in the question, not in the code. I added the image in the end of question field.

Comment: Ok, but that's actually a different error. The import was not successful and you don't handle the exception. It seems that `TestJsModule`has a a problem with `Promise`.

Comment: @a better oliver, because everything works in Chrome, I conclude that it is the problem on IE side. Can I solve it without Polyfill?